# Google login for FastAPI

Tags: fastapi, authlib

I am using the code below for google authentication. There is two end points (/login and /auth). At the first time I can sign in with my google account but when I want to change it, it does not ask me for Google credentials, it automatically sign in with my previous account. Is there any help?

Here is the sample code:

```
@app.route('/login')
async def login(request: Request):
    # absolute url for callback
    # we will define it below
    redirect_uri = request.url_for('auth')
    return await oauth.google.authorize_redirect(request, redirect_uri)

@app.route('/auth')
async def auth(request: Request):
    token = await oauth.google.authorize_access_token(request)
    # <=0.15
    # user = await oauth.google.parse_id_token(request, token)
    user = token['userinfo']
    return user
```

You can find the full code here:
https://blog.authlib.org/2020/fastapi-google-login

Comment: I assume you have to implement a logout to invalidate the current google session before using the login endpoint again.. or wait for it to timeout

Comment: I already implement a logout and wait for a timeout. No help. When I delete browser cache, the login works. But I need to delete browser cache again and again.

Answer (score 0):

clear your session first
@app.get('/logout')
async def logout(request: Request):
request.session.pop('user', None)
return RedirectResponse(url='/')

or clear your cookie